# Вывод многомерного массива из базы дынных средствами php

Tags: php, mysql

Всех приветствую!

При выводе записей из двух таблиц в многомерный массив PHP, далее в JSON, происходит дублирование.

То есть, вместо того, чтобы вывелось https://ibb.co/nMJMOy 
выводится https://ibb.co/n4JSwJ

Вот код php https://ibb.co/hE4xDy

База данных имеет 2 таблицы:

```
Images

[
newsId(varchar255)
imageName(varchar255)
imageLink(varchar255)
]

News
[
newsId(varchar255)
newsAddDate(varchar255)
newsText(varchar255)
]
```

Изначально идея состояла в том, чтобы каждая новость, хранящаяся в базе данных располагала бы информацией о картинках, для новости (ссылки на картинки), и чтобы можно было добавить больше одной картинки, я создал вторую таблицу и связал поле "newsId" в таблице "news" с полем "newsId" в таблице "images".

Уже целый день вожусь с этим, никак не могу понять почему так происходит.

И да, я полный новичок в этом деле, везде искал материал по этой теме, не нашёл (или плохо искал).

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь покажет, в чём моя ошибка.

Comment: Вы бы лучше сюда скрины добавили и код тоже

Comment: Продублируйте нам while, какое-никакое решение, но предложим.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить вложенный массив, где у каждой новости будет свой массив фотографий? Ну можно как-то так вроде..

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','exp');
if($connect){

    $result = [];

    $queryResult = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM images, news WHERE images.newsId = news.newsId");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){

        $images = !empty($result[$row['newsId']]['images']) ? $result[$row['newsId']]['images']: [];
        $images[] = [
            'name' => $row['imageName'],
            'link' => $row['imageLink']
        ];

        $result[$row['newsId']] = [
            'newsId' => $row['newsId'],
            'newsAddDate' => $row['newsAddDate'],
            'newsText' => $row['newsText'],
            'images' => $images,
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Мда.. что-то чересчур костыльно получилось. Но вроде делает что нужно. Ключами основного массива будут ID'ы новостей.

**P.S.**

Порекомендовал бы давать название полям в таблице немного иначе. Первичный ключ (primary key) лучше всегда просто называть `id`. (У вас в таблице `news` вместо `id` дано название `NewsId`). А если же какая-то таблица `B` связывается с таблицей `А`, то ее внешний ключ правильнее будет назвать `A_id` (в вашем случае у таблицы `images` дано название `NewsId`, что в целом почти ок). Ну и сам запрос тогда бы уже выглядел не так

```
SELECT * FROM images, news WHERE images.newsId = news.newsId
```

А как-то так

```
SELECT * FROM images, news WHERE images.news_id = news.id
```

Что, согласитесь, понятнее читается.

Вообще не знаю какие там есть правила и стандарты "грамотного" наименования в SQL, но таблицы я обычно именую в единственном числе, нижнем регистре и с подчеркиваниями. (напр. product, image, image_of_product). Поля таблиц тоже (name, text, product_id, created_at). Просто PHP фреймворки на основе таких названий всегда генерирую красивые наименования связей и моделей, вероятно это какой-то там стандарт. Но повторюсь - не в курсе, просто на мой взгляд так понятнее, поэтому рекомендую.

Comment: Люди пишут не как им нравится а юзая PSR, хорошо это или плохо другой вопрос и скорее философский)

Comment: То что есть единые стандарты - скорее хорошо чем плохо. Просто не о всех стандартах я осведомлен, и многое частенько просто перенимаю, когда вижу некую стандартизированность в коде (поэтому и написал что не в курсе, насколько подобное наименование в действительности стандарту соответствует). По запросу наименования таблиц PSR c ходу найти ничего не удалось, так что если проясните как правильнее давать названия таблицам и полям с точки зрения общепринятых стандартов - будет, наверное, хорошо..